# Why does'nt the turtle module work for me at Visual Studios?

Tags: python, visual-studio, turtle-graphics

So, I've been stuck for months not being able to import, and use the turtle module. I've tried a various of tricks/methods but nothing works out, idk why.
Some of the things i try out is to import the module, and then setup the screen, which does'nt work. The only thing yet this far ive tried on Visual studios that works out is to type in 1+1 which in the outputs says 2.

I've already loaded in python on vs and installed the app 100% correctly but it just does'nt work. I've also tryed out other commands except for the 2 past named ones.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

but now these does'nt work out for me...

The only error message i get is

> "Invalid syntax"

Comment: Can you paste complete traceback of error? Did you get the syntax error only from those two lines of code?

Comment: Shaik moeed rn it doesnt say anything once i click enter, but in the past it just stood like "invalid syntax in line 1"

Comment: It's not clear yet whether this is a turtle issue library or a general Python issue.  Do simple Python expressions, e.g. `[a for a in range(10)]` work correctly?

Comment: Shaik nothing happens it just says "exited with code=0 in 0.073 seconds"